# How to let my users save their configuration on Google Drive without sahring my developer credentials.json?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

There is something I don't understand, when it comes to using the Google Drive API.

I'm trying to develop a desktop application that lets the user save his config file to his personal Google Drive, so he can use the same config from any computer.

The [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) guide has an example how to let a user authenticate, but this example requires the user to have the "credentials.json" file that I created in the Google Console. My understanding is that I should not share this file publicly.

So can I allow users to synchronize their configuration on multiple desktop computers without giving them the app's credentials?

```
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Based on the question and comment on the answer below, what is the end-goal of this? The users having a built exe application and using their account to log in?

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the [TOS](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html) for using the Google apis

> Asking developers to make reasonable efforts to keep their private keys private and not embed them in open source projects.

If you are giving your users the copy of your python code. You may not give your users your credetinals.json file. You must instead instruct your users on how to create their own credetinals.json file.

## Solution

Solution to not sharing your credentials its to teach the users of your application to create their own credentials.

Comment: So is there no way I could just let my non-technical users simply click on "allow app to access my Google Drive" and let my code do the work for them? 
Creating their own application and tokens is not a simple thing to do.

Comment: you can't give someone else you project credentials this is against the TOS.

Comment: I understand this. I'm looking for another way of making an application that can connect to a user's google drive.

Comment: There is no other option you can only connect to a users drive account if you have their consent. To request consent you use Oauth2 which is what you are doing now.   You could try a service account but again the user would need to create credentials for a service account as you cant share your credentials with people.

Comment: The credentials file has nothing to do with getting the users consent. It seems to be about identifying an app for Google using a private key. But I don't get why there isn't a way to identify an app with a public key that can be shared with the code or with  the released binary.  How does it make sense for Google to allow desktop apps to use the API, but make it impossible to distribute the app to users?

Comment: If you give me your credeitnals json file for an installed application.  I can use it to my hearts content. In my own application.  The consent screen will show your name and contact info, the users of my application will think my app is your app.  So then i can go about spamming your project on Google cloud console until you get your account banned.   Google will see it as you and not me.   The users of the app will see it as you stealing there data.    Do you see why you cant share it.   The main point is its against the TOS that you aggreged to when you created your project.

Comment: the credentials file you download from google developer console not only identifies your application but it allows your application to request consent of the user. Desktop applications are a gray area but the credentials file is stored with in the compiled application. Python is a scripting language you cant compile it which means you will be including it in clear test.  Again its against the TOS just have your users create their own its doable.  I even have a youtube video on how to create installed app credentials make one for your users.

Answer (score 0):

I have 1 idea. Use selenium and automate process of creating credentials.json. In this way non-technical users not need to do anything and with this automatic process credentials.json shall be created using users google account.
Apply this idea and you shall see good results.